# Getting back empty response body when making a POST request using Angular + Express

Tags: node.js, angular, express

I'm trying to make a simple POST request but I'm getting an empty response back from the server. I've sifted through all the SO questions regarding this topic and tried the solutions posted but to no avail.

I've tried changing the request header options to use `'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'` and set bodyParser in my express app as `app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));` but that didn't work either.

**auth-service.service.ts**

```
login(loginInfo: object) {
    return this.http.post<loginInfo>(this.loginUrl, { "test": "test" })
    .pipe(
        catchError(this.handleError)
    );
 }

 private handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
    if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
       console.log('An error occured:', error.error.message);
    } else {
       console.log(`Backend returned code ${error.status}, ` +
      `body was ${error.error}`);
    }

    return throwError('Something bad happened; please try again later.')
 }
```

**login.component.ts (calls the login service method)**

```
onSubmit() { 
    const loginInfo = { username: this.username.value, password: this.password.value };
    this.authService.login(loginInfo).subscribe(
         resp => { console.log(resp); },
         err => { console.log(err); }
  )
}
```

**server.js (I've defined routes here but they're not relevant)**

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const api = require('./routes/api');

const app = express();
const port = process.env.port || 3000;

app.use((req, res, next) => {
     res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
     next();
})
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use('/api', api)
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
     res.send(JSON.stringify('Hello from server'));
})

app.post('/login', (req, res) => {
     let userData = req.body
     res.send('Request body: ' + JSON.stringify(userData));
})


app.listen(port, function () {
     console.log('Server running on localhost: ' + port);
 });
```

I'm console logging the following:

`Backend returned code undefined, body was undefined`

`Something bad happened; please try again later.`

When I try using Postman, however, I get the response I expect (i.e. `Request body: {}`)

I'm not sure as to why a response is retrieved when done through Postman but not when done through the app.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: can I see your network call in browser, I want to see the request headers.

Comment: @BhushanBabar Nothing shows up in the network. I'm confused as to why this is as well. Sorry, I'm quite new to http calls in Angular in general so I may be missing something very obvious.

Comment: what is your angular version, and I would suggest you to first try with simple code, I mean remove `pipe` you are using for error handling, remove the return type `post<loginInfo>` , just try your code with very simple code, I would even say that to make even simpler subscribe in the service itself and console the result, and if you don't see network call, you should put a debugger to see if your service code is reachable.

Comment: @BhushanBabar I'm using 6.2.9. I'll try your suggestions and see if I can resolve it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `body` for `POST` request in `auth-service.service.ts`:

```
import { HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';

login(loginInfo: object) {
  const body = new HttpParams()
    .set('test', 'test');
  return this.http.post<loginInfo>(this.loginUrl, body)
    .pipe(
      catchError(this.handleError)
    );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. This doesn't seem to fix the issue.

Comment: @JacobL do you have angular interceptors in your app?

Comment: Nope I do not (sorry for the verbose response, there's a 15 char minimum for responses)

Answer (score 0):

try using express.json its missing

```
app.use(express.json());
```

and

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));
```